# Determine if button is clicked right after textbox value change

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling, mouseevent

I have screen like following:

[image]

I have bound the `change` event of textboxes under box2 column.Now the change event is fired when a user clicks out after changing the values but I do not want the user to click the Buttons in the screen after making the change in box2 textboxes.

This means I want to prevent the click of the buttons if a user is clicking on them right after making a change in any of the textboxes but at the same time the `change` event of the particular box should fire as usual.

Is it possible to find out the last widget or the event fired in an event,It sounds odd but I can stop the click of the button if I can determine that very last thing happened was the change of textbox.

```
 //Change listener of textboxes
  jQuery('#parent').on('change','.textbox',function(e){

        var btn = jQuery(this).closest('.button');         
        if(btn.length){  
          jQuery(this).addClass('red',500,function(){ 
             var poObj = {'changedRef':{'val':jQuery(this)}};      
             btn.triggerHandler('click',poObj);
          });
        } 
      });

    //this is a buttonClick  
      jQuery('.button').on('click',handlerBtnClick);
```

You can see from the code that change on the textbox is actually calling the click of the corresponding button that is in its row.But the problem is if a user clicks on a button of different row after making a change in a box.

Ideas please?

Thanks

Comment: could you try to set a global variable on first time change, then check the variable value to determine if it is already changed ?

Comment: could you not disable the button onchange and the re-enable it onblur or when something else is focused?

Comment: @Pete Unfortunately I cant disable the buttons as it will affect another logic involving the number of disabled buttons.I tried `jQuery('button').on('click',function(){return false})` in the `change` event but the original click handler of the button fires..I assume because change event takes time.

Comment: @RanjeetSingh that will work but I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: if you did that bit of jquery to return false, it would do it for all buttons and you would need to unbind the current event attached to the button first.  You need to provide some code and html structure otherwise we can't help you here

Answer (score 0):

p.s.

**event.type** gives the event that was triggered.

Have

```
1)Click function for your button( eg:func1() )

2)Change function for your textboxs( eg:func2() )
```

Declare a global variable ( for e.g: eventTp)

When func2() gets called, assign **event.type** to the variable eventTp .
When func1() gets called , check if eventTp variable has the value **(Change)**.

If yes, then give return false, which will prevent the event from happening.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to determine if the last action was a change made on textbox when the button is clicked.Event.type gives type of current event

Comment: Yes. When the change event gets triggered for the textbox , you are storing the event.type to a variable. When the click event gets triggered for the button, you will check the value of the variable,with which you can find if the previously triggered event,was the change event.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this ?

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

document.getElementById('box2').addEventListener('change',function(){
  button.disabled = true;
});

document.getElementById('box1').addEventListener('change',function(){
  button.disabled = false;
});
```

```html
<input type='text' id='box1'>
<input type='text' id='box2'>
<button id='button'>Button</button>
```